# How to rename a flash drive (not just a partition)

Tags: mac, usb-flash-drive, rename

How do I rename a flash drive on a Mac? I know how to rename a partition, but how do I rename the actual drive? I highlighted what I want to rename in the image below:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. What's showing in your picture is how the factory firmware on the flash drive reports it make (manufacturer name) and model (product name) to the host machine. To change it, you would have to re-flash the device's firmware (or, if it's not flashable, replace its ROM) with a firmware image that reports a different manufacturer and product name.